# Remove all numbers in a column

Tags: r

Remove numbers and characters from a column mixed with text but retain only the text.

[image]

Use this to create the dataframe.

```
mydata <- tibble(camp = c("Platinum 2018-03","Reboarding 2018","New Acct Auto Jul18", "Loan2019-4"),
                  Acct = c(1, 33, 6, 43),
                  Balance = c(222, 7744, 949, 123))
```

When this is done the camp column would become.

I want the camp column to be left with  `Platinum`, `Reboarding`, `New Acct Auto`,  `Loan`.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_remove` to remove the characters other than the letters

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
   mutate(camp = trimws(str_remove(camp, "(\\s+[A-Za-z]+)?[0-9-]+")))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  camp           Acct Balance
#  <chr>         <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 Platinum          1     222
#2 Reboarding       33    7744
#3 New Acct Auto     6     949
#4 Loan             43     123
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response but this doesn't solve my problem. It only concatenated all the words but the numbers are still visible. I also do not want the words to the concatenated, i want them exactly how they are but with the exclusion of the numbers.

Comment: This time it worked a little better but the New Acct Auto July 18 didn't change except that it didn't do much for the 3rd row. Instead of "New Acct Auto Jul" i have it as "NewAcct Auto Jul18".

Comment: @Omomaxi  For me, it is removing the `July 18`.  What is your `stringr` version?  If you want to update the original object, `mydata <- mydata %>% ...`

Comment: Do you mean what version of R i have?

Comment: Oh, i just found it. it's 1.4.0

Comment: @Omomaxi  I also have `stringr` as `1.4.0`

Comment: I re-tried it and it worked. Thank you so much...... Quick question though, could you explain the code please.